Easy admin collection field add item
I got an issue with my CollectionField. I'm a collections of items just inserted. But when i try to add a new item the id of the new form is the same of the last just inserted. So the last element is updated with new one. Any Idea?
I tested every entities involved but it seems all works.

I finally found the error but not the cause. When the field-collection.js counts the items it has a wrong value.
parseInt(collection.dataset.numItems) counts one less item so the new item has same id of the last item, as i said.
I'm wondering if it's a field-collection bug or I did something wrong in the rest of the code. Thanks.
